# Merge jQuery array with each (function)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to add the selects and inputs values in an array with jQuery. 
So the array looks like this:

```js
var testarr=[
  [
    "Option1",
    "",
    "Text1"
  ],
  [
    "Option2",
    "Input_1",
    ""
  ]
];
```

with the empty values.

Here I do not get further, how can I combine arraytest and arraytest_1 so that it looks like testarr?

```js
var arraytest = []; 
$('select').each(function(){ 
  arraytest.push($(this).val()); });
```

```js
var arraytest_1 = [];
$('input').each(function(){
  arraytest_1.push($(this).val()); 
});
```

```html
<div>
  <select id="idTest1" class="select_css" name="selectTest[]">
    <option value="" selected>Option</option>
    <option value="Option1">Option1</option>            
    <option value="Option2">Option2</option>    
  </select>

  <input type="text" class="input_css" data-room="1"  name="input_1[]" />
  <input type="text" class="input_css" data-other="1" name="input_2[]" />
</div>

<div>
  <textarea name="textareaTest[]" placeholder="Test" class="textarea_css" id="textarea1"></textarea>
</div>

<div>
  <select id="idTest2" class="select_css" name="selectTest[]">
    <option value="" selected>Option</option>
    <option value="Option1">Option1</option>            
    <option value="Option2">Option2</option>    
  </select>

  <input type="text" class="input_css" name="input_1[]" />
  <input type="text" class="input_css" name="input_2[]" />
</div>

<div>
  <textarea name="textareaTest[]" placeholder="Test" class="textarea_css" id="textarea1"></textarea>
</div>


<button id="addButton">Values in Array</button>

<div id="arrlist"></div>

<script>

$("#addButton").on("click", function() {

    var arraytest = []; 
    $('select').each(function(){ 
      arraytest.push($(this).val()); 
    }); 

    var arraytest_1 = []; 
    $('input').each(function(){ 
      arraytest_1.push($(this).val()); 
    });

    var testarr=arraytest+arraytest_1; //(var testarr=[["Option1","","Input2",""],["Option2","Input1","","Text"]];)

    for(var i=0; i<testarr.length; i++) {
      text = '<div>'+testarr[i][0]+'<br>'+testarr[i][1]+'</div><div>'+testarr[i][2]+'</div>';
      $("#arrlist").append(text);
    }
});
</script>
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Thanks, but i need the array like that:

    var testarr=[["Option1","","Input2",""],["Option2","Input1","","Text"],...];

so that i can display the data in the for loop:

    for(var i=0; i<testarr.length; i++) {
          text = '<div>'+testarr[i][0]+'<br>'+testarr[i][1]+'</div><div>'+testarr[i][2]+'</div>';
          $("#arrlist").append(text);
        }

Answer (score 0):

With JQuery you can merge array with the following function :
https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.merge/

```
$.merge( [ 0, 1, 2 ], [ 2, 3, 4 ] )
```

This will output :

```
[ 0, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4 ]
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use $.extend()

```
var testarr = $.extend({}, arraytest , arraytest_1);
```

[jQuery.extend()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, but i need the array like that:

```
var testarr=[["Option1","","Input2",""],["Option2","Input1","","Text"],...];
```

so that i can display the data in the for loop:

```
for(var i=0; i<testarr.length; i++) {
      text = '<div>'+testarr[i][0]+'<br>'+testarr[i][1]+'</div><div>'+testarr[i][2]+'</div>';
      $("#arrlist").append(text);
    }
```

Comment: you can use json for example; 
var data = [ 
 {"Id": 1, "name": "aaa"}, 
 {"Id": 2, "name": "bbb"}, 
 {"Id": 3, "name": "ccc"}
];
   $.each(data, function(i, item) {
    alert(data[i].name);
});​

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why this answer was not already posted, this is the simplest:

```js
var arr1 = ['a', 'b'],
    arr2 = ['c', 'd'],
    result = [arr1, arr2];

console.log(result);
```

For your case, that would simply be `testarr = [arraytest, arraytest_1];`

Or if you need a generic solution that works with any number of arrays, use `push`:

```
testarr = [];
testarr.push(arraytest);
testarr.push(arraytest_1);
//etc
```